# How to reference a variable in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Is it possible in Visual Basic 6 to make some variable to reference to another variable, so when one changes, so does the other?

I know it is possible to use `Set` operator for objects. But how to make this work for integer type variables? The only way I am aware of is to wrap the variable inside an object.

Answer (score 2):

Not through the language itself. You could use a class as you mentioned, the other way is to use the Win32 API.

Specifically

HeapAlloc to allocate memory. You will store the returned address in a Long variable.

Then use RTLMoveMemory renamed as CopyMemory to transfer data in and out of the allocated memory.

```
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
    "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, _
    ByVal Length As Long)
```

[This website](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/how_to_do_pointers_in_visual_basic.aspx?df=100&forumid=1232&exp=0&fr=26&select=5094) has a more complete example of using pointers in VB6.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom Reference Object class which sounds like it would do exactly what you are looking for.  You can read up on it and download it here: http://battaglia.homedns.org/vbguyny/development/visualbasic6/visualbasic6_20070218.htm

Answer (score 0):

try putting variable A in a textbox then make an on change event on the text box., then put the value the text to variable B.

textbox1.text = A

onchgange textbox1
B= textbox1.text

its wat im using., the most easiest way for me

Answer (score 0):

The method of assigning a variable to a text box to set a reference is wrong. It does not do what is stated.  Assigning a variable to a text box or assigning a text box to a variable **COPIES** the content of the text box to the variable.  It is not setting a reference to it!